# JTA Requires new doens't work in same Injected class

Tags: java, cdi, jta

Well, i have a class injected by CDI like following:

```
@Named
@RequestedScoped
public class MyClass{
   @Transactional
   public void start(){
     for(int i = 0; i < 100;i++){
        //do some logic
        forceSave();//should save immediately
      }
   }

   @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void forceSave(){

   }
}
```

Unhappy it don't work. The forceSave() works in same transaction that start() method. I need create another class put forceSave() in this other class and everything works, like this:

```
 @Named
    @RequestScoped
    public class MyClass{
       @Inject
       private MyClassTwo two;
       @Transactional
       public void start(){
         for(int i = 0; i < 100;i++){
            //do some logic
            two.forceSave();//should save immediately
          }
       }

    }

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyClassTwo{
 @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
       public void forceSave(){

       }
}
```

This second solution works fine, but is very ugly. I need create always another class to use a new transaction. There is another way to fix it ?

Comment: You are calling forceSave() directly which will not involve the transactional proxy. For it to participate in its own new transaction you need to call it via the proxy bean. In your second case that is exactly what you are doing. You are injecting the proxied instance of `two` hence it works. Have a look at how to self inject the bean in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633687/can-an-ejb3-bean-self-inject-and-call-its-own-methods-via-ejb-container

Comment: Can i use something like this: ((MyClass)CDI.current().select(SomeBean.class).get()).newTransaction();  Right ?

Comment: What Setu says is correct, you need to enforce a bussiness method invocation. Try to avoid using `CDI.current()` though, instead just self-inject the bean. Alternatively, you can try and inject `Instance<MyClass>` which you then resolve.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example ?